# Pokemon go update gmail login issues

Tags: pokemon-go

I just updated the Pokemon go app and now it won't let me log in. I click google gmail to log in and then click allow and it loads for a second and continues to go back to the google allow screen and after two times it turns blank and just sits there and continues to play the music and if I does load it just sits there until I turn it off.

Can you please help me so I can fix this because I would really hate to lose my account and all that hard work.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone first? This sounds similar to when the logon servers where slammed and people would get stuck on the loading screen or kicked back to the main screen.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and I tried reinstalling the application and it continues to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND A FIX!! When you click "Login With Google" click the safari compass instead of logging in through the app. After you click allow it will say if you want to open this page in Pokemon GO. Click Yes and the Gyrados loading screen should pop up.